# Can a Bard restart a Glamour Bard's Enthralling Performance after being interrupted or is the ability used for that day?

Tags: dnd-5e, dungeons-and-dragons, bard

I have a friend playing with a Bard and wants to use the class ability, but he is asking me if the person he wants to enchant leaves the place for a moment during the use of the ability he can interrupt it and restart when the creature is back.

And if he starts using the ability and after half a minute the creature leaves the place for, 24 seconds, for example, and come back. Would it be possible to wait those 24 seconds and after that keep with the ability for half extra minute to make it work?

I have a personal view different from his, but wanted to clarify so we can get into a sense.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### Performing for one minute is a prerequisite of the ability

The ability starts off by saying:

> **If you perform for at least 1 minute**, you can attempt to inspire wonder in your audience by singing, reciting a poem, or dancing. **At the end of the performance**, choose a number of humanoids within 60 feet of you **who watched and listened to all of it**...

(Emphases mine)

From this, we know that your performance needs to last at least 1 minute, the target has to watch all of it, and you perform the charm at the **end** of the performance. So...

1. The ability is not used up until you decide to use the ability at the end of the performance.
2. If the intended target leaves or is no longer observing the performance for whatever reason, they are not a valid target even if they return. You would need to begin a new performance that they observe for the whole duration.